# Generator Function - What does the star on = mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I am going through the [Nodeschool exercise on Generators](https://github.com/isRuslan/learn-generators).

The solution to the second exercise is this:

```
function *factorial (n) {
  var result = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    result *= i;
    yield result;
  }
}

for (var n of factorial(5)) {
  console.log(n)
}
```

What does the `result *= i` mean?

Comment: it's shorthand for `result = result * i`

Comment: multiplication. `result = result * i`

Comment: Check this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Multiplication_assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition:](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition)** There is also a family of operators that are a combination of an
>   assignment and an arithmetic operator. **These are called compound
>   operators**. They can make your code more compact.

Let's see some of them with examples:

```
var a = 5;
a = a + 3; // 8
```

a shorter way:

```
var a = 5;
a += 3; // 8
```

In your code this:

```
result *= i;
```

is equivalent to:

```
result = result * i;
```

Comment: I feel like a fool, I think the star of generator function was clouding my basics :! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*= is a multiplication assignment operator,

`result *= i` is equal to `result = result * i`

source [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I think you confused the `*` on `function*`, which is how you declare a `generator`, with that in `*=`. The `*` in second scenario is the shorthand operator for `a = a * b;`, as already mentioned but the second is the identifier for the compiler to distinguish a generator from a normal function